# Trouble re-installing data.table on 32bit computer

Tags: r, data.table

I have a 32bit Windows computer (it's a work computer that can't be changed), running R 3.6.3.
When I install data.table 1.13.2, it fails to install (see below). Any help is highly appreciated!

````
Warning in install.packages: 
problem copying C:\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\00LOCK\data.table\libs\i386\datatable.dll to C:\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\data.table\libs\i386\datatable.dll: Permission denied.
Warning in install.packages: 
restored 'data.table'.

library(data.table)
...
error: This is R 3.6.3 but data.table has been installed using R 4.0.3. The major version must match. Please reinstall data.table.```
````

Comment: Which install command did you use?

Comment: I used install.packages

Comment: You can get older versions of the data,table package from the [Archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/data.table)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with write permission. You can set and see where R installs packages by calling

```
.libPaths()
.libPaths() <- c("new/path/to/install/libs")
```

Make sure you have read write permission to that location.

I also think you have two copies or a previously installed copy of R 4.0. Which resulted in R throwing that error.

Use `install.packages("data.table")` to install the package in R 3.6

Comment: OK, I uninstalled and erased all copies of R except 3.6.3 from my computer, fixed the permissions, and was able to install. However, I still get this: ```error: This is R 3.6.3 but data.table has been installed using R 4.0.3. The major version must match. Please reinstall data.table.```